# Excel- Add sequential names to column based off of named range but skip names if duplicate name exists in adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I am creating a simple schedule for our engineering rotation. Some background information, our team currently has 6 engineers that must go on a weekly 5 am rotation. There is also a 2nd shift rotation that each engineer must go on for 2 weeks at a time.

I have the list of engineers captured within a range that automatically sizes itself using the following function.

`=OFFSET(LookupLists!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(LookupLists!$B:$B)-1,1)`

In this way if I ever need to add or remove people from the rotation it is easily done by adding or removing names from that list.

I have defined a variable in a cell denoted "Days on second shift" (Currently 10 days or 2 work weeks) so I can easily modify the amount of time each engineer will spend on 2nd shift.

To enumerate the 2nd shift schedule I used the following function.

`=INDEX(Engineers,MOD(ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A1)-1)/LookupLists!$C$2,0),LookupLists!$D$2)+1)`

This enumerates a list of engineers X amount of days long, where x = days on second shift and then moves onto the next engineer in the list "Engineers".

The Tricky part is the 5 am schedule. If an engineer is on second shift they are not apart of the 5AM rotation. I am looking for some kind of function such that the 5am schedule is enumerated via the list defined via "Engineers" but if the engineer is on 2nd shift their name is skipped and the list moves onto the next value until all X amount of engineers are accounted for and the list starts over. Preferable this list would autogenerate based on a function that will update when I update either the list of engineers or "Days on 2nd shift."

Example of the schedule Sheet

[image: Schedule Sheet screenshot]

Example of the variables used

[image: Screenshot of variables used]

Example of Desired Output

Desired Output

[image: desired output]

Comment: Hi @DanfossEngineer ,, check my post below,, I've solved the issue ☺

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a more elegant answer using the following formula:

`=INDEX(Engineers,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Engineers)-1/(Engineers<>Schedule!$D3),MOD((ROWS($1:1)-1),ROWS(Engineers)-1)+1))`

I appreciate the help though!

Comment: It's really a better & smart one,, a one shot solution,,, U get +10 ☺ **But since U are handling large data set then definitely need others like,, how could U generate set of 10 employ's name as I dis in Col U the Evening Engineer, you can't think for keyboard entry,,, also the Weekdays !!**

Answer (score -1):

*To solve this issue you need few Helper Columns:*

**:Caveat:**

*For proper visualization I've used only two data sets, are **Jack** & **John**, you need to extend them as needed.*

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Insert `1` in cell M2.
- Formula in cell M3: `=M2+O$2`.
- Formula in cell Q2:

  `=IFERROR(IF(ROW(A1)<=O$2*P$2,ROWS($A$1:A1),NA()),"")`
- Formula in cell R2:

  `=INT(((ROW(A1)-1)/5))*5+0`
- Formula in cell U2:

  `=VLOOKUP(Q2,M$2:N$7,2)`
- Final array (CSE) formula in T2:

  ```
  {=INDEX($N$2:$N$7,SMALL(IF((INDEX($N$2:$N$7,,1)<>$U2),MATCH(ROW($N$2:$N$7),ROW($N$2:$N$7)),""),IF(ROW(A1)<=5,ROWS(T$2:$T2),ROWS(T$2:$T2)-R2)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1))}
  ```

---

**N.B.**

- Finish array (CSE) formula in cell T2 with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.
- For neatness later on you may *hide Helper Columns*.

Comment: This solution only works till line 50 after which it breaks down entirely.

Comment: @danfossengineer ,, no you need to adjust all formula as soon you add new data this will work without failure. Also Name in column N,,,

Comment: @DanfossEngineer ,, check the helper column M the last value is 51,,, currently working with 50 rows,, pull it down & add more name in column N,,, and accordingly adjust other formulas!!

Comment: Write your concern that why this has been down voted,,, help me to improve,,, plzz avoid baseless voting !!